# emacs: spell checking: mark all typos

Tags: emacs, spell-checking

When using emacs, is there a way to mark *all* typos in a document in one go, instead of going from one typo to the next?

It would be nice if that would be possible such that code sections could be ignored by the user (see my question [emacs: restrict spell check to certain environments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72026119/3852630)).

Comment: Your second paragraph seems unrelated to this question. Please consider removing it (one question per post). Thx.

Comment: If you are using `flyspell-mode` in combination with `ispell`, simply running `ispell` (with <kbd>M-x ispell</kbd>) will show you all the typos, but it also forces you to deal with them right away so it may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Drew: Thanks, but the 2nd paragraph wasn't intended to open a 2nd question. An answer to this question would also resolve the older one since I know which portions are text (where the typos should be corrected) and which portions are equations (where typically things are marked as typos erroneously).

Comment: @BlackBeans: Thanks. I tried your suggestion, but this doesn't seem to work. What is supposed to happen? I activated flyspell and run `ispell`, but when I try to scroll down to see more marked typos, no typos are marked.

Comment: I accidentally stumbled over this one: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/39199. So apparently there is a command `flyspell-buffer` which does what I need.

Comment: This one I also found helpful: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/a0sswd/how_do_i_change_the_highlighting_of_spelling/ It explains how to change the markers of flyspell. I found that if I use `Red3` and a line instead of a wave for `flyspell-incorrect` and deactivate markers for `flyspell-duplicate`, I can look through the errors very fast.

Comment: I now saved this configuration in `.emacs` which uses `inverse-video` to mark the typos, much easier to see, and ignores duplicates: `'(flyspell-incorrect ((t (:inverse-video t)))))` and `'(flyspell-duplicate ((t nil)))`.

Answer (score 0):

I summarize my three comments in this answer, in the hope that it is helpful:

From https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/39199: You can use the emacs command `flyspell-buffer`.

I found it easier to see the typos when I change the flyspell markers as suggested by
https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/a0sswd/how_do_i_change_the_highlighting_of_spelling/ in `.emacs`:

```
'(flyspell-duplicate ((t nil)))
'(flyspell-incorrect ((t (:inverse-video t)))))
```

(saved from `customize-face`).